# Reusable search component in react - css failing on overflow of text

Tags: css, reactjs

I have created a reusable search component, i am facing two issues on this.

- overlapping the search text on the svg icon -  enter more text on the input box
- entering more text the text-indent not staying - text goes left side when more text is entered

I have added the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-moon-7q8dv?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the overlapping text on the search icon, I would simply solve it by adding some padding to the input field.

```
input{
  padding-right: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

For the text-indentation not staying while the input field is active, I'm not sure how to solve it in a clean way. You could add a div with the same background color and width as the indentation, and then just give it an absolute position.

**Second Issue Workaround**

Instead of using text-indent, we can use **padding-left** and it will work properly, kindly see this one [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046638/css-text-indent-on-input-field-doesnt-update-the-caret-position-until-you-start)

Comment: Thanks Stephan, had a doubt will that be a clean way, even i was thinking in that way. But since its a reusable component it should be clear isn't. So also adding the padding-right is cleaner way

Comment: so if i am adding padding-right: 5px, i should reduce the width -5px from current isn't

Comment: but i tried the solution of yours that didn't worked can you for the codesandbox and check

Comment: You don't need to reduce the width of your element when using padding if you set the box-sizing to border-box. I forked and updated your sandbox with the changes here. https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-firefly-99tu1

Comment: okay cool, got it so in border-box it will be added isn't. And how can we solve the text indent in a better way if there is any

Comment: figured out the issue, instead of using text-indent if i used padding-left it works, Thanks for the help . adding this info too in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046638/css-text-indent-on-input-field-doesnt-update-the-caret-position-until-you-start

Answer (score 0):

This might help with keeping the content of the input from overlapping the search icon.

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.css-btdvqp {
  background:#e1e1e1;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.css-btdvqp .css-vrkvd {
  width: 85%;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the above won't work on what you have there. It keeps scrolling and overlaps the icon. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: can you fork the codesandbox and try it, because of width i dont think wont it be a better way of solving it

Comment: The width is for the nested input and that's going off of the parent div, which it looks like you set to 240px;